# Explain plan for mysql performance. Query taking more than 8hrs and still executing

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, query-performance, query-tuning

I read various blogs and documents online but just wanted to know how i can optimize the query. I am unable to decide if we have to rewrite the query or add indexes in order to optimize.

I tried adding indexes also on INDEX(DSR_BOOKED_BY, dsr_booking_date,
      dsr_cnno, dsr_status, dsr_cnno, dsr_dist_pin, id) but no luck.

The RAM size of the server is 16GB and innodb bufferpool size is 12GB

This is the query which is taking almost 8 hrs but no result in the end

```
select ob.BRANCH_CITY orig_city,dstb.BRANCH_CITY dest_city,round(sum(CASE WHEN left(dsr_cnno, 1) IN ('V', 'E', 'X') THEN
IFNULL(value, 0) ELSE 0 END),2) Premium,
round(sum(CASE WHEN left(dsr_cnno, 1) NOT IN ('V', 'E', 'X') THEN  IFNULL(value, 0) ELSE 0 END),2) Non_Premium
from ( select DSR_BRANCH_CODE,dsr_cnno,DSR_AMT,
((dsr_amt) +((((dsr_amt)-ifnull((select max(ndsr_ins_amt) from ndx_dsr_table where ndsr_cnno=dsr_cnno ),0)-ifnull((select max(ndsr_serv_charge) from ndx_dsr_table where ndsr_cnno=dsr_cnno ),0) -ifnull((select sum(dr_extra_amt) from dsr_revenue where dr_cnno=dsr_cnno ),0))-(((dsr_amt)-ifnull((select max(ndsr_ins_amt) from ndx_dsr_table where ndsr_cnno=dsr_cnno ),0) -ifnull((select max(ndsr_serv_charge) from ndx_dsr_table where ndsr_cnno=dsr_cnno ),0)
-ifnull((select sum(dr_extra_amt) from dsr_revenue where dr_cnno=dsr_cnno ),0) )*ifnull(((select fr_discount from fr_mas where fr_Code=dsr_cust_code)),0)/100)) *ifnull(((select (case when dsr_invdate <'2017-05-01' then ifnull(fr_fsc_per,0) else 30 end) from fr_mas where fr_code=dsr_cust_code limit 1)),0)/100)) as value, dsr_cust_code
,dsr_dest_pin from dsr_table d where  dsr_booking_date BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-06-30' AND LENGTH(dsr_cnno)=9 
AND DSR_BOOKED_BY ='F' AND dsr_status<>'R' AND dsr_cnno NOT LIKE 'J%' AND dsr_cnno NOT LIKE '@%'
AND dsr_cnno NOT LIKE '576%' AND dsr_cnno NOT LIKE 'I3%' AND dsr_cnno NOT LIKE '7%'
AND dsr_cnno NOT LIKE 'N%' and d.dsr_dest_pin>0) zz
inner join fr_mas f on f.FR_CODE=zz.dsr_cust_code
inner join branch_mas ob on ob.BRANCH_CODE=zz.dsr_branch_code and ob.BRANCH_LOC='L'
inner join serv_dest_mas dm on dm.SERV_PIN=zz.dsr_dest_pin 
inner join branch_mas dstb on dstb.BRANCH_CODE=dm.SERV_BRANCH and dstb.BRANCH_LOC='L'
where dstb.BRANCH_CITY in ('HYD','DEL','AMD','GGN','BLR','PNQ','MUM','CHE','CCU','NOD')
and ob.BRANCH_CITY in('HYD','DEL','AMD','GGN','BLR','PNQ','MUM','CHE','CCU','NOD')
group by orig_city,dest_city ;
```

and the explain plan output is

```
    id  select_type         table          type    possible_keys                                                       key                       key_len  ref                             rows  Extra                                                                
------  ------------------  -------------  ------  ------------------------------------------------------------------  ------------------------  -------  -------------------------  ---------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     1  PRIMARY             ob             range   PRIMARY,FK_BRM_CITYMAS                                              FK_BRM_CITYMAS            4        (NULL)                            10  Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
     1  PRIMARY             <derived2>     ref     <auto_key2>                                                         <auto_key2>               3        billingdb.ob.BRANCH_CODE      319051  Using where                                                          
     1  PRIMARY             f              eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   9        zz.dsr_cust_code                   1  Using index                                                          
     1  PRIMARY             dm             ref     PRIMARY,IDX_SDM_SERVPIN_STATUS1                                     IDX_SDM_SERVPIN_STATUS1   3        zz.dsr_dest_pin                    2  Using index                                                          
     1  PRIMARY             dstb           eq_ref  PRIMARY,FK_BRM_CITYMAS                                              PRIMARY                   3        billingdb.dm.SERV_BRANCH           1  Using where                                                          
     2  DERIVED             d              ref     idx_dsr_bkdate,idx_dsr_bookdby_ccd_cnno,idx_dsr_bkdby_ccd_bkd_stat  idx_dsr_bookdby_ccd_cnno  1        const                      182365315  Using index condition; Using where                                   
    10  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  fr_mas         eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   9        billingdb.d.DSR_CUST_CODE          1  (NULL)                                                               
     9  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  fr_mas         eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   9        billingdb.d.DSR_CUST_CODE          1  (NULL)                                                               
     8  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  dsr_revenue    ref     PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   12       billingdb.d.DSR_CNNO               1  (NULL)                                                               
     7  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ndx_dsr_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   12       billingdb.d.DSR_CNNO               1  (NULL)                                                               
     6  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ndx_dsr_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   12       billingdb.d.DSR_CNNO               1  (NULL)                                                               
     5  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  dsr_revenue    ref     PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   12       billingdb.d.DSR_CNNO               1  (NULL)                                                               
     4  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ndx_dsr_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   12       billingdb.d.DSR_CNNO               1  (NULL)                                                               
     3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ndx_dsr_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                             PRIMARY                   12       billingdb.d.DSR_CNNO               1  (NULL)
```

Comment: You need to work on your derived table 'd' which is fetching '182365315' rows.

Comment: @skelwa yes. I am not able to figure out how to do that. I added indexes mentioned above. Please let me know how i can achieve the optimized query

Comment: Your index is not created in right order. Try creating index like (dsr_booking_date, dsr_cnno,
DSR_BOOKED_BY, dsr_status, dsr_dest_pin).

Comment: This is a mess. I think the only realistic option is to start over

Comment: @Strawberry you mean to rewrite the complete query? I dont think that could be possible now at this time. Any thing else that you would suggest? help!

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391514/explain-plan-in-mysql-performance-using-using-temporary-using-filesort-using -- I copied the extra rows from here to there.